# Equivalent document.querySelector inside Mutation Observer dynamic elements

Tags: jquery-selectors, mutation-observers, switchery

I'm using [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen to the new added elements and it's working fine for all elements but for [Switchery jQuery](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery) Plugin it doesn't because Switchery get element by [document.querySelector]

This is my code...

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observerjQueryPlugins = function (repeaterWrapper) {

_.each(repeaterWrapper, function (repeaterItem, index) {

    var jq_nodes = $(repeaterItem.addedNodes);

    jq_nodes.each(function () {

        // Color Picker (Working Good)
        $(this).find('.element-wrapper.element-wpcolor .color-picker').wpColorPicker();

        // Switchery using document.querySelector and i need to know the
        // equivalent way to do it inside this loop .. like that

        // Of course this code is WRONG
        sw_current = $(this).find('.switchery-element');

        var switchery = new Switchery( sw_current, {
                disabled: false,
                size: '',
                color: '#8ce196',
                secondaryColor: '#ddd',
                jackColor: '#fff',
                jackSecondaryColor: '#fff'
        });

    });
});

}

new MutationObserver(observerjQueryPlugins).observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Switchery is not a jQuery Plugin. That's why the sample code in [GitHub](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery) uses document.querySelector to acquire element to apply it.

As you use jQuery to find elements, you need to use jQuery.[each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) in order to process every DOM element for Switchery.

The following is an example to find element by jQuery and apply Switchery to each element. so, do the similar thing after `sw_current = $(this).find('.switchery-element');` in your code.

```js
 $(function() {
        sw_current = $(this).find('.switchery-element');
        sw_current.each(function() {
         var switchery = new Switchery(this);
        })

    });
```

```css
@import url("http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css");
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="switchery-element" checked />Check 1
<p/>
<input type="checkbox" class="switchery-element" checked />Check 2
<p/>
<input type="checkbox" class="switchery-element" checked />Check 3

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
```